# c++ init member of superclass in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, member, superclass

I don't get the point why my member is not initialised. I have something like this:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A() {member = 0;}
    int getMember() {return member;}
  protected:
    int member;
}
```

and

```
class B : public A
{
  public:
    B() : A() {member = 10;}
}
```

When I try to get the value of *member* from B it is always 0.
What do I miss here?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Ctor is public now.

Comment: @chris: this would still construct the `B` object and assign `10` to `member` as far as I can tell. I'd like to be enlightened if it isn't, though.

Comment: The constructor is private.. so I assume you can't have new B(); 
I haven't done C++ in a while.. so I could be wrong.

Comment: @LewsTherin: you are right. This points towards the posted code not being the real code in which case the behavior may come from aspects not shown in the quoted example.

Comment: Show more code. From this small part, nobody can tell really, just guess.

Comment: This code, once you make B() public works correctly and does what you'd expect it to do. I assume what you're missing is somewhere else in your code; as Olaf said, without more code we can't help.

Comment: For the reasons described above, please post a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem. Please make it **complete**, so that we can copy-paste it into a text editor, and **minimal** -- I'd expect that you could create a 20-line program that demonstrates the error. See http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Comment: @LewsTherin: Sorry, my bad. Of course it should be public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried two things and they both give the expected result:

```
class A
{
  public:
    A() {member = 0;}
    int getMember() {return member;}
  protected:
    int member;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A() {member = 10;}
};

int main() {
    A* a = new B();
    cout << a->getMember() << endl;
    B b;
    cout << b.getMember() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This returns

```
output:
10
10
```

You can check the code at http://ideone.com/FArIAC

Comment: I really have no clue what went wrong but now it is working. Maybe no update from the compiler or whatever. Thanks!